# OwnCloud and Azure Active Directory integration

Tags: owncloud, entra-id

Is it possible to integrate ownCloud (https://owncloud.org) with Azure Active Directory for auth?

Comment: [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=owncloud+azure+integration) says yes https://bitnami.com/stack/owncloud/cloud/azure

Comment: @chicks, as I know Bitami is a VM with OwnCloud for Azure, but there are no words about Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Today answer is no : Azure AD can't be used directlty as an Authentication Directory for Owncloud.

If you synchronize your AD with an Azure AD (using AAD Connect) and expose your Owncloud Server through Azure AD Proxy (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-proxy-publish/), you should achieve your goal even it's more a workaround.

Hope this help :-)

Stanislas